# Django-admin, Users and Permissions

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-admin

In django an inactive user can't login, but if he is already logged in then he can still use the website until he logs out. Where i can to check why is not work correctly?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about this, then you'd need to implement something to check the current user on every request and log them out explicitly if their account is inactive. Middleware would be a good place for this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class InactiveUserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and not request.user.is_active:
            logout(request)
            return redirect(your_login_url)
```

Place this in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` directly after the `AuthenticationMiddleware`, and you should be good to do.